# Toilet vent plumbed upstream of toilet inlet

Tags: plumbing

I ran a 2" toilet vent upstream of the toilet using a 3x2 combo. The toilet flange is in a 3" combo which is inline and within a foot of the 3x2 combo vent. will this fly with UPC. If not, can I leave it plumbed that way and install a vent downstream of the 3" toilet flange / 3" combo? Basically, upstream and downstream vented.

Comment: If I follow your question yes and yes. UPC? Building code?